# Div messed up in Opera Mobile when zooming in

Tags: html, css, mobile, cross-browser, opera-mobile

I' using a div on my website with the following css class:

```
width: 100%;
margin: 6px auto 0;
height: 51px;
line-height: 50px;
text-align: center;
max-width: 1290px;
```

There are several links in this div with the following css class:

```
display: inline-block;
width: 7.5%;
```

Note: I've also tried the following:

```
display: inline;
padding: 0 20px;
```

This layout works fine on all major browsers (including Android stock browser), however im experiencing nasty problems on Opera Mobile when zooming in. Have a look:
[image: Opera Mobile Zoomed in]

It is being wrapped into 2 lines basically.

( div id="menu" )

Comment: Note: I could always use a float left, but I would like to have the a elements in this div centered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple:

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

to the #menu class fixed this problem.